# go unittest cannot load file

Tags: unit-testing, go

1、`go test config_test.go`,always file,error: open conf/config.yml: The system cannot find the path specified
2、source code is ok
3、how do `go test file`  sucess   in different directory

Comment: `go test`(like most of the go tool subcommands) works on _packages_ and not on files. Accessing something like testdata/config.yml works properly if you run `go test`.

Answer (score -2):

Your working directory during tests is different.

You may want a workaround with dynamic calculation of the config dir path, for example:
http://www.kaihag.com/external-assets-working-directories-and-go/

Comment: The working directory during execution of `go test some/package` is deterministic and equal to `$GOPATH/src/some/package`. So these recommendations in the linked article are unnecessary complex. The statement "Your working directory during tests is different." is misleading as the working directory during test ist the only one being fixed: During execution of the executable you'll have different working dirs.